# SQLSRV queries are not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I just setup a PHP server using IIS and a Microsoft SQL server, both running on the same Windows Server 2008 machine. I installed the SQLSRV driver from Microsoft on PHP, because I want to use my SQL Server database in PHP.

Connecting to the SQL Server instance runs fine in the code but when I try to execute queries, it doesn't work anymore. The same queries I try to run from the php code are working in other programs, such as my SQL Server Manager. Even simple commands like 'USE dbname' aren't working, while they do work from SQL Server Manager.

This is the PHP code that I'm using. When I run the code it says connected and after that Error Selecting DB.

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect("TRANSIP-VPS\SQLEXPRESS");
if( $conn === false )
  { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
echo "Connected ";
      $selectDB = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "USE Vitare");
      if($selectDB === false){
        die("ERror selecting DB");  
      }

$tsql = "CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)";
  $getProducts = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
  if ( $getProducts === false)
        {
        echo "Error creating table";
        die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
echo "stuff";
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['username'];
```

When I run sql_srverrors() instead of printing 'error selecting DB' , it only gives me the word 'Array', nothing more, no error message, nothing.

Comment: Does the table schema `Vitare` exist ?

Comment: Yes it does, it appears under databases in SQL Server management

Comment: Try `USE Vitare;CREATE TABLE ...` or `CREATE TABLE Vitare.dbo.Persons ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to connect to the database:

```
$serverName = "TRANSIP-VPS\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Vitare" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: I'll try it but I don't think it will work, because other simple commands like Select * FROM Vitare.dbo.users also didn't work.

Comment: A connection is linked to one database, I think `sqlsrv_query( $conn, "USE Vitare");` will not work. The above code connects to the database.

Comment: Now it doesn't even say connected anymore. I just gives me the error Array again. So perhaps there's something wrong with the database Vitare. But that would be strange because the database works fine in SQL server management and in a C# script I wrote.

Comment: `FormatErrors` is not a standard PHP function, have you defined this somewhere? Try `var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());`

Comment: The error message is too long to for a comment, so see this link:

Comment: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR". Connect with username and password `$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Vitare", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password" );`

Comment: I got it all working now. I had to create a new non-windows auth user and give him permission to the database. Thanks for the help.